# split element of array in multiple array bash

Tags: bash

I need to read a file into an array.
Then store in a **new** array only the first column of each line

example file:

```
aa,1,2,3
bb,4,5,2
cc,7,1,4

mapfile -t arrFile < file
```

so in arrFile, I got all the rows

```
${arrFile[0]} , returns 'aa,1,2,3'

echo ${arrFile[0]} | cut -d ";" -f1 returns 'aa'
```

How can I copy the firstcolumns from arrFile in another array, possibly without looping in a while

Comment: No need for external commands like `cut`. Bash (even Bourne shell) has suffix removal, using `${var%%<pattern>}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why copy? Perhaps it is enough if you simply use `${arrFile[0]%%,*}` ?

Or you can copy, using `arr2=(${arrFile[@]%%,*})`